# AspectJ join point with simple types

Tags: java, int, aspectj, pointcut

Are there defined join points in arithmetics that I can catch?

Something like:

```
int a = 4;
int b = 2;
int c = a + b;
```

Can I make a `pointcut` that catches any one of those lines? And what context will I be able to get?

I would like to add a `before()` to all int/float/double manipulation done in a particular method on a class, is that possible.

I see in the [AspectJ docs](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-joinPoints.html) that there are defined join points for object initialization and method calls. Is declaring an `int` an object initialization and does the `+` operator count as a method call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, `+` does not correspond to a method call of any kind in Java.

You could for instance create your own wrapper-class that encapsulates an integer, or use `BigInteger` and do a `pointcut` on the `add` method.

Comment: I started making wrappers, when I remembered AspectJ and though that it might be easier. 

I'm trying to make a program for visualizing small algorithms, so I would like to be able to apply the program to any code without having to modify it.

Maybe Java isn't the right language to use, any suggestions? I would like to avoid having to create a new language/compiler.